# Qual o propósito da função with_jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

Estou aprendendo a escrever UserScripts (para [TamperMonkey](http://tampermonkey.net)) e praticamente todos os exemplos que eu vejo fazem uso de uma função `with_jquery`:

```
function with_jquery(f) {
   if (!jQuery)
      return;

  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
};
```

Apesar dos scripts serem diferentes, a implementação dessa função específica é sempre a mesma. Com o resto do script sendo invocado fazendo uso dela:

```
//Declaração de with_jquery()

with_jquery(function($){
    // Resto do UserScript
});
```

Minha impressão inicial era que isso servia para dar acesso ao objeto jQuery (`$`) dentro do script, mas esse exemplo funciona da mesma maneira no SOpt, com ou sem uso do `with_jquery`:

```
var bar = $("#h-top-questions");
bar.append("teste");
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Você pode adicionar manualmente arquivos com a extensão `.user.js` para a aba com endereço [`chrome://extensions/`](http://chrome://extensions/) (no chrome, outros navegadores baseado em Chromium talvez não funcione):

> Clique na imagem para ver a animação:
>
> [image: Greasemonkey nativo no Chrome]

É como se o Chrome tivesse o Greasemonkey nativo (creio que seja isso mesmo).

No entanto os scripts instalados diretamente sem tampermonkey não permitirão acesso direto as variáveis definidas pela página, apenas variáveis nativas são acessíveis. Então se no seu arquivo `.user.js` tentar acessar diretamente `$`, `jQuery`, `window.$` e `window.jQuery` retornará `undefined`.

No entanto se você injetar um script via `document.createElement` usando string ele conseguirá acesso, então por este motivo disto `"(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";`, ele converte a função para string e injeta na página.

> **Nota:** No *tampermonkey* para Chrome/Opera não é necessário pois ele permite o acesso direto a qualquer variável da aba, aparentemente o Greasemonkey também permite o acesso direto atualmente

---

Outro **possível** situação é evitar conflitos com `$` em diferentes bibliotecas javascript que o usam, por exemplo se o site usar a biblioteca [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com) que pode sobrescrever a variável `$`, por isto o uso de `(jQuery);` ao invés de acessar diretamente.

Note que este tipo de técnica não é usada somente em `userscripts`, ela é usada por plugins jQuery também.

Além disso também esta função também pode ser usada para coisas como:

- Muitos userscripts fazem uso do jQuery
- As pessoas necessitam rodar um userscript somente em páginas com jQuery, tipo para corrigir ou modificar comportamentos do jQuery ou até fazer um tipo de proxy nele.
- Para detectar se o jQuery já foi carregado, se caso não for ele fica em loop esperando o jQuery ser carregado (isso conforme quem escrever o userscript)

Note que no sites da rede só usam jQuery, mas um userscript pode ser usado em diferentes sites, mesmo que você crie ele para um site especifico ou desenvolvido para ser usado em diferentes sites propositalmente.

**Explicação do código:**

```
function with_jquery(f) {
   if (!jQuery) // <-- Verifica se existe jQuery na página, ou seja ele já foi carregado
      return; // <-- Se não tiver sido carregado

  //Se o jQuery estiver disponivel na página que o userscript é injetado então a partir daqui carrega o script solicitado

  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";

  //Passa a variavel jQuery para o escopo do callback para evitar conflitos com outras bibliotecas no uso do $
  script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";


  document.body.appendChild(script);
};
```

E esta linha especifica:

```
"(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
```

Passa o jQuery para o contexto da função chamada, não é algo necessário de fato, mas digamos que seja um proxy que afete o comportamento do jQuery ou por N motivos existe algum problema de contexto das funções, isto eventualmente armazenaria dentro do contexto atual, sem necessitar de acessar o global (no caso `window.`) diretamente e evitar conflitos com múltiplas bibliotecas

Por exemplo, supondo que o site use jQuery e YUI, o objeto `$` poderá entrar em conflito, então geralmente usamos [`$.noConflict();`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), mas podemos também passar para o contexto da função, ou seja se `$` sendo o argumento de um callback:

```
with_jquery(function($){ //<-- aqui
    // Resto do UserScript
});
```

Será uma variável diferente do `$` global (que é o mesmo que `window.$`), se por acaso um outro script ou userscript carregar uma lib como a YUI que use `$` no escopo global, ele poderá reescrever a variável `$` fazendo com que o seu userscript pare de funcionar, pois provavelmente a YUI irá sobreescrever o `$`, mas o que você espera é usar o jQuery e não o YUI, se você usar diretamente assim poderá ocorrer o problema de conflito:

```
$(".foo").bar();
```

Mas se fizer assim:

```
with_jquery(function($){
    $(".foo").bar();
});
```

Você estará acessando o mesmo que a variavel jQuery o que evitaria o conflito com outras libs como a YUI, e não precisará escrever o código de maneira longa:

```
jQuery(".foo").bar();
```

Podendo assim manter o uso do `$` para se referir ao jQuery, mesmo que outra lib afete o global.

Comment: Boa. Não sabia das outras bibliotecas que usam `$`, e isso explicam bem a necessidade de explicitar a referência à `jQuery` no `with_jquery`. Valeu.

Comment: @Gabe resposta atualizada, haviam detalhes que desconhecia do navegador Chrome.