# Executar JS em página de terceiro

Tags: javascript, userscripts

Gostaria de saber todas as formas possíveis de como executar um JS(local) em uma página de terceiro, onde a minha real intenção é manipular o **frontend** mesmo para me dar a visualização customizada de uma página x.

Eu já consigo fazer isso utilizando o programa [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) onde é possível através do recurso "*AutoResponder*" eu substituir o JS ou CSS existente em uma página pelos meus arquivos locais, mas eu gostaria de conhecer de acordo com a experiência de quem souber...quais as outras maneiras de se fazer isso?

Comment: Tampermonkey ou Greasemonkey.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Essas duas ferramentas vão me ajudar muito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível injetar JavaScript nas páginas usando um recurso chamado *userscripts*. Isso é bastante usado, inclusive, a [organização do GitHub com membros do StackOverflow em português](https://github.com/stackuserflow) tem alguns [*scripts* que nós desenvolvemos](https://github.com/stackuserflow/stackoverflow-tampermonkey-greasemonkey) para nos auxiliar no dia a dia. Você pode ver mais detalhes nessa [publicação do meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5780/18246).

Você pode usar extensões como [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=pt-BR) (Chrome) e [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (Firefox).

O Chrome também aceita nativamente a inserção de *userscripts*, existem detalhes sobre isso [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157102/18246).

Answer (score 0):

Teria que pensar em algo assim:
Digamos que teria uma caixa de texto, para digitar alguma coisa, como nome de usuário:

```
User Name : <input ... value="Nome">
```

Agora, se digitasse assim:"onmouseover="evento

```
<input ... value=" "onmouseover="evento ">
```

Ou alguma coisa assim:
Temos uma caixa de texto, tipo de um navegador, se digitarmos tal coisa, pode aparecer "Não foi encontrado nenhum resultado para [palavra pesquisada]"
E se digitarmos: Código, e o navegador ou outro site não achar nada, se não tiver nenhuma segurança, pode executar o script.
Digamos que isso é um código HTML:

```html
<div>Não foi encntrado nenhum resultado para <script>alert("script")</script></div>
```

Exemplo 2:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function Pesquise(){
/*Script do navegador ou parte de pesquisa de um site*/
document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML  = "Não foi encontrado nenhum resultado para " +  document.getElementById("CaixaPesquisa").value;
}
</script>

<input id="CaixaPesquisa" type="text" value="Código aqui"/><input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" onclick="Pesquise();"/>

<div id="Result">

</div>
```