# Abrir um navegador e executar um javascript direto no console através de outra linguagem de programação

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, console

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:
Imagine a seguinte cena. Você abre o navegador, abre o console e logo em seguida coloca algum código javascript ali pra realizar alguma tarefa.

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar um script em alguma linguagem (como C por exemplo ou qualquer outra dentro do possível) que seja capaz de abrir um navegador e executar um código javascript nele de forma automática.

To pesquisando sobre o assunto mas sem sucesso em encontrar alguma resposta de tal possibilidade.

Agradeço quem puder responder.

Comment: Dá uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188051/executar-js-em-p%C3%A1gina-de-terceiro) guerreiro, talvez possa ajudar!

Answer (score -1):

A resposta é: **depende**...

Se você quer simplesmente executar um script JavaScript, você tem que encontrar uma forma de criar um arquivo HTML que possua uma tag `<script>` direcionada para o script desejado, e, em seguida, executar essa página. Isso pode ser feito até com `bash`, ou `python3`.

Se você quer transformar uma parte do código construído em JavaScript (transformando C++ em Javascript, por exemplo), que é o que eu entendi que você quer, você terá que passar por um processo chamado de "[transcompilação](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/t/transcompiler.htm)".

Depois de alguns minutos de pesquisa, encontrei [essa lista](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS). Talvez te seja útil.

O terceiro caso, que [já possui uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188051/executar-js-em-p%C3%A1gina-de-terceiro), inclusive, é de quando você produz certos scripts padrão para páginas web que podem servir como "coringas". Não vou entrar em detalhes, mas é bem simples e útil.

O quarto caso é de o site acessado através de um link no seu site tenha seu JavaScript alterado. Não sei se é possível, mas não imagino os desenvolvedores deste site hipotético concordando com isso.

Em todo caso, possível é. Mas, dependendo o que você quer fazer, pode não valer a pena.

Comment: "Se você quer transformar uma parte do código construído em JavaScript..."  Não seria isso. Por exemplo: Imagina a seguinte tarefa manual de eu abrir um site, depois abrir o console e em seguida colocar algum script js pra alguma finalidade qualquer. Eu gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de executar esta sequência de passos através de alguma outra linguagem de programação. O máximo que eu encontrei até agora pesquisando foram scripts simples via .bat de abrir o navegador mas isso nem chega perto do que estou interessado em saber.

Comment: Como eu disse, **se eu entendi o que você quer fazer**, dá pra executar isso usando `bash`. Pra isso, você deve saber qual navegador vai ser usado e a sintaxe para abrir um link ou HTML com ele. Pra isso, use `man [comando]`. Ex: `man firefox`

Answer (score -1):

### Executar JS automaticamente

Para executar automaticamente um Javascript no "console" automaticamente, você não precisa de uma outra linguagem. Basta um plugin como Tampermonkey para conseguir esse efeito.

Eu mesmo uso o Tampermonkey para rodar diversos JS em diversos sites, para mudar alguns comportamentos específicos desses sites.

### Webdriver

Agora, para poder usar o navegador inteiro a partir de uma linguagem de programação, inclusive rodar JS específicos como se tivesse no console, basta usar o Webdriver da linguagem, que transforma o navegador numa API utilizável programáticamente.